# Infinity - infinity calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (x-1)e^{-1/x}-x$$

I know that this limit equals $-2$ but I don't know how to prove it. I can only get to $\infty-\infty=?$

Comment: May be, you could start using $x=\frac 1y$ and use Taylor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(x-1)e^{-1/x} - x = x(e^{-1/x} - 1) - e^{-1/x}$$

$$\lim x(e^{-1/x} - 1) = \lim \frac{e^{-1/x} - 1}{1/x}$$

Use L'hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $e^{-1/x} = 1 - \tfrac 1x + O(\tfrac 1{x^2})$:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} (x-1)e^{-1/x}-x & = \lim_{x\to\infty} (x-1)(1 - \tfrac 1x + O(\tfrac 1{x^2}))-x \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} (x-1) + -\tfrac 1x(x-1) + O(\tfrac 1{x^2})-x \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} x-1 + -1 +\tfrac 1x + O(\tfrac 1{x^2})-x \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} -2 +\tfrac 1x + O(\tfrac 1{x^2})\\
&= -2
\end{align}$$